# Is this namespacing issue my problem or is it an IDE problem?

Tags: php, namespaces, phpstorm

I have a namespacing notification on the PhpStorm IDE and I can't see how to resolve it.

## IDE

- PhpStorm 2023.1

## Structure

I have a class amongst various other classes by other vendors, my class sits in this folder:

> /home/classes/vendor/namespaceOuter/namespaceInner/subnamespace

The autoloader.php file sits in `/home/classes/`

My **class file** sits inside the above folder, and is `ClassFile.php`. Within, this has the `namespace` set out as here:

```
<?php
Namespace namespaceOuter\namespaceInner\subnamespace\ClassFile;

use \exception;
use \PDOexception;

class ClassFile {
      ... 
}
```

## Problem

The PhpStorm IDE tells me:

> Namespace name doesn't match the PSR-0/PSR-4 project structure

## NOT a problem

- The autoloader works perfectly.
- The class and its children and peers all work perfectly on the live website, the issue seems purely with the IDE informing me we're not following the PSR-0/PSR-4 .
- These are our own classes and not set by or involving Composer (other classes do).

## Attempted Solutions

- I have tried to change the namespace to make it call from root (`\namespaceOuter\namespaceInner\subnamespace\ClassFile;`) within the Class file but this doesn't remove the notification.
- I have tried to use the suggested fix by the IDE which in fact makes a bunch of new child folders in the current class' folder (`/home/classes/vendor/namespaceOuter/namespaceInner/subnamespace/namespaceOuter/namespaceInner/subnamespace/ClassFile.php`) which is clearly impractical and wrong.
- Other established classes (such as PHPMailer) within the `vendor/` folder do not have the same notice on their class files.

## Reading

I have read the PHP [Namespacing documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) as well as the [PSR-4 documentation](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) which includes this example:

| Fully Qualified Class Name | Namespace Prefix | Base Directory | Resulting File Path |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| \Symfony\Core\Request | Symfony\Core | ./vendor/Symfony/Core/ | ./vendor/Symfony/Core/Request.php |

While this **IS NOT** a Symfony project, the inconsistency between qualified namespace and file path implies this is not an issue.

| Fully Qualified Class Name | Namespace Prefix | Base Directory | Resulting File Path |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| \namespaceOuter\namespaceInner\subnamespace\ClassFile.php | namespaceOuter\namespaceInner\subnamespace | classes/vendor/ | ??? |

## Question

Is this namespacing incorrect somehow or is there an issue with the PHPStorm IDE suggestion (I believe so) -- if so, how can I check/ update / confirm / fix this?

Thanks

Comment: From what I see you would need to show real namespace names/screenshots and not made up ones. Most likely it will be an IDE config issue... but it depends. This `vendor` part in the path is what's confusing me... Is it really a composer package? I personally do not know how to approach this unless I can see the real stuff (where the project is, where that problematic stuff is / composer package or actually a part of the app own code / how that thing is defined in composer.json etc etc).

Comment: @LazyOne No these are our own classes/namespace but other peer classes are downloaded using Composer. I found the issue was PHPStorm Resource Root wasn't set to the right place.

Comment: Let's say you have `\App\Models\User` class and It is located in `PROJECT_ROOT/src/App/Models/User.php` file. So it's a file that is part of the project itself. Then PhpStorm in the `Settings/Preferences | Directories` should have that `PROJECT_ROOT/src/App` folder marked as **Source Root** and linked to the `App` namespace. With Composer packages it's different -- the IDE should be taking the info from the composer.json file for that package. And should not really bother about the matching path since it's a 3rd party code in the IDE eyes.

Comment: So you have it solved now? Or still not?

Comment: @LazyOne yes thank you, but because I answered it myself I need to wait 2 days to tick it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After spending a long time writing out this question I found the answer was:

In PhpStorm --> Settings --> Directories the `/home/classes/vendor/namespaceOuter/namespaceInner/subnamespace` directory was marked as a "Resource Root". By replacing this with `/home/classes/` as the Resource Root ([**Documentation**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/content-root.html#root_types)) the notification magically disappeared.

So this issue appeared to be an IDE issue rather than a namespacing issue.

**EDIT:**

The project root is `/home/` .
The `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is `/home/public_html` . 
The `classes/` folder is now a "Resources Root" and the `/home/` folder is the "Content Root" for the PhpStorm project.

This works because (I think) The autoloader sits in the `classes/` folder, so PhpStorm "Resources Root" should be the same folder the PHP Autoloader sits in so that PhpStorm can find all the autoloaded classes

Comment: Where is the project root? `/home/classes/` or just `/home/`? If it's `/home/classes/` then  you do not need to mark the root folder as a Resource Root as that's the default behaviour. Resource Root is needed when you have it in a subfolder (e.g. a typical Laravel project -- `PROJECT_ROOT/public` is a web accessible path/web root. You would need to mark it as Resource Root so the IDE can resolve paths relative to that when you are referring to images/css/js files in your HTML (the most common usage case))

Comment: *"This works because (I think) The autoloader sits in the classes/ folder"* The IDE does not care where the class is located actually. It *should* work OK without marking `classes` as a Resource Root. Please try that. Because in NONE of the Laravel/Symfony projects that I had to work with I had to mark `vendor` as a Resource (except the actual web roots or alike). Must be something else, e.g. wrong initial Resource Root mark...